# Severe pain in knees after running

Tags: running

I am totally new here in this fitnees forum. I am telling my problem from the start.

I started running in the morning for around almost a month ago.

I used to run 1.5 kms with a more or less constant speed of 2.86 metres/second and then I walk normally for another 6 kms and finally last 1.5 kms I jog pretty much slowly.

I was not having any upto 7th day. On the morning of my eigth day I started running as I do,when I reached the stage where I jog last 1.5 kms before returning home,I started feeling enough pain in my left knee that I couldn't jog anymore,I just walked home.

From the next day the pain elevated so much that I felt very hard to even walk(even when I am normally roaming around the house or whichever activity I tried to do which involves my knee to work)

Still I thought of continuing my walk for a week more and my running or jogging is completely stopped, I only used to walk around 4 kms.

Then the pain grew even more instead of reducing,so I completely refrained myself  from going out in the morning.

After a rest period of 20 days I felt much better and the pain was gone,so i started running again for 1.5 kms as before then walk.
It was ok for about 8 days but after that
when I stopped after running 1.5 kms, I again felt immense pain in my both knee and my both knees were shivering,I felt hard to stand even at that moment but i waited sometime and walked back home.

After reaching home,the pain was gone roughly after a rest of 30 mins. I wasnt feeling the immense pain anymore and I could walk without pain.

This went on for about 10 days and everyday this same thing used to happen.
But on 10th day I noticed that If I run as I used to with a speed of 2.86 metres/second,I was unable to detect pain during running,but if I reduce my speed pretty much and run slow,I again feel my same pain in my left knee,which I dnt know why doesnt bother me if I run fast.

So this is the situation untill now.
Please provide me some reasons and ofcourse any exercise of something to cure this.

Comment: Have you got good running shoes?

Comment: Sorry,I basically dont know what charachteristics are needed for them to be good running shoes, but I never felt any sort of uncomfort because of my shoes and they are lightweight.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Fitness.SE. Generally, we will shy away from medical advice on this site. Diagnosis and prescription shouldn't be done over the internet, rather brought to your doctor. With that said, we do allow question on injury prevention. It's a bit of a fine line but feel free to edit your question; it can then be voted on to re-open.

Comment: You should use shoes with good shock absorption and not run every day but instead every 2nd day. Also try strengthening the muscles around your knee by doing walking lunges and narrow stance squats 2-3 a week. If the pain persists you should see a doctor.